# Changing Attribute Onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a special way to modify the attribute onclick?

```
    var btn = document.getElementById("deletebutton" + j);
    btn.id='deletebutton'+mreplace;
    btn.onclick = 'deleteDiv('+mreplace+')';
```

The id will change but the onclick remains constant.

I'm trying to switch out some Id's and data to reconstruct a page after an element has been deleted from the page. In this case I have 7 divs, when i erase say the 3rd one, I want to modify the other divs so that their text is updated--- This i have accomplished --- now the problem is just updating the onclick function of the delete button, so it will delete the correct div when clicked.

full function being called.

```
function deleteDiv(id) {

    var div = document.getElementById("idBox" + id);
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

    // If countbox > id

    if (countBox() > id) {

        var j = countBox();

        while (j > id) {

            var div = document.getElementById("idBox" + j);
            var mreplace = j-1;
            var replace = j+1;
            var html = div.innerHTML;

            var curInnerHTML = html.replace("Question "+replace,"Question "+j);
            div.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;           

            div.id='idBox'+mreplace;
            var btn = document.getElementById("deletebutton" + j);
            btn.id='deletebutton'+mreplace;
            console.log(mreplace);
            btn.onclick = 'deleteDiv('+mreplace+');';


            j = j - 1;

        }

    }

}
```

here is the html generated of one of the divs that Can be deleted

```
<div class="Cbox" id="idBox1">
                            <div class="leftpart">Question 2:</div><div class="rightpart"><span class="target" data-field="3" contenteditable="true">Questijjon # 2</span>
                            <br>

                            <select class="super" name="3" onchange="getCombo(this)">
                                <option value="MC" name="0" data-field="0">
                                    Multiple Choice</option>
                                    <option value="TF">
                                        True/False</option>
                                        <option selected="true" value="INT">
                                            Integer</option>
                            </select>High: <span class="intHigh" data-field="3" contenteditable="true">50</span>  Low: <span class="intLow" data-field="3" contenteditable="true">15</span>
                            <form action="" method="post">

                                <input class="deletebutton" id="deletebutton1" value="-" name="delete" onclick="deleteDiv(1);" 1'="">
                            </form></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: *"The id will change but the onclick remains constant."* In what way? How are you checking? Why do you think it hasn't changed?

Comment: Why do you want to use inline events to bind a handler.  Use javascript to bind them.

Comment: chrome element inspecter

Comment: @Sushanth--: Being pedantic, that **is** JavaScript.

Comment: http://puu.sh/7rV0p.png these numbers should be the same, delete and deletebutton

Comment: @user2647561: What you're doing *will* change the event handler, provided the string can be compiled. My guess is that `mreplace`, when substituted into a string, creates a string that doesn't do what you want. We'd need a lot more context to help you with that.

Comment: @user2647561: *"puu.sh/7rV0p.png these numbers should be the same, delete and deletebutton"* Nope, that's not how SO works. Links rot. Put the relevant information **in** the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. What I meant was to avoid mixing javascript with HTML. I used the wrong wordings :)

Comment: @Sushanth--: The above is pure JavaScript. What you meant (I suspect) was to use a DOM2 handler, not a DOM0 handler. And I'm not at all sure it would make a difference, because the question lacks crucial information.

Comment: What more info would you need?

Comment: Why not just do: `btn.onclick = function() { deleteDiv(mreplace) }';`

Comment: It doesnt work with this set-up. So is it impossible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @user2647561: *"What more info would you need?"* Gosh, I don't know. What does `mreplace` contain? What result do you expect? What result do you see instead? What should the button do? What does it do instead? What's in the off-site picture you've linked but not included in the question?

Comment: One sec I'll upload everything then.

Comment: @user2647561: Usually, creating a [small, self-contained, replicating example](http://sscce.org) is the best way to go. Nine times out of ten, you figure out the problem in the process; the tenth time, you have something well-contained that people can reasonably help you with.

Comment: Okay I know, but usually I just mess up syntax or something. I can't find any examples online of people changing the attribute on-click, i thought there might be a special way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        btn.onclick = function() { 
        deleteDiv(mreplace);
         };
```